# Android - как загружать файлы с сервера в локальную папку Assets

Tags: android, файлы, файловая-система

Добрый день! 
По факту я хочу сохранять файлы с сервера в папку, в которой они не будут видны никому кроме этого приложения, просто работал только с папкой assets.

подскажите как прописать это в методе:

```
File myIcon = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null) + File.separator + "myIcon.png");
```

получается что мне нужно прописать свой путь вместо getExternalFilesDir(), но я не знаю какой путь у assets

Comment: вы не сможете сохранить файл в папку `/assets`. используйте `internal storage`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что-то сохранить в `assets` в рантайме [невозможно](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3760626/3212712), т.к. всё её содержимое упаковывается в АПК файл на этапе компиляции. Т.е. папка `assets` используется лишь для хранения любых файлов, которые не подходят по типу для помещения в ресурсы но нужны в момент первого запуска.

Вам придётся писать файлы куда-то ещё, в `assets` не получится.

Comment: Все ресурсы в приложении доступны только для чтения (не для записи или изменения) , если коротко :)

Comment: @pavlofff, да, но можно ведь извернуться и другой своей приложенькой поправить содержимое АПК при наличии рута, что, в общем, позволит записать файл в ассеты... Но, конечно, думаю, ТС этого на самом деле не хочет)

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы организовать работу только Вашего приложения с файлами сохраненными с сервера в локальной папке, Вам необходимо организовать хранение этих файлов во внутренней памяти Андроид устройства. При сохранении файлов во внутренней памяти устройства доступ к ним будет организован только для Вашего приложения (если телефон не рутован). Т.е. файл получит права доступа которые имеет только Ваше приложение. При сохранении же файла во внешнем носителе технически доступ к файлу может получить любое приложение. При сохранении файла во внутреннюю память Вы можете получить его директорию в виде File, вызвав метод getFilesDir(). Для создания файла  можно использовать конструктор File(), который передает элемент File например:

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
```