# Скачивание изображений с сервера и сохранение их в определённую папку проекта

Tags: android

Как сделать так, чтобы после загрузки (или после первого открытия) приложение скачивало с сервера изображения и сохраняло их в определённую папку проекта?

Comment: Какого проекта? Что вы понимаете под "папка проекта" в контексте запущенного на устройстве приложения?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Извините за ожидание, я имел ввиду папку самого приложения (app\src\main)

Comment: Простите, но `app\src\main` это как раз и есть папка проекта. В контексте работающего приложения ее нет.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Это я просто корневую назвал. В этой папке ещё находится папка assets, в которой находится папка drawable. То есть в итоге мне нужно загружать в папку `app\src\main\assets\drawable`
Или вы имеете в виду, что в процессе работы приложение не может обратиться к этим файлам?

Comment: Да, ресурсы приложения доступны только для чтения.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Android - как загружать файлы с сервера в локальную папку Assets](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/637212/android-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-assets)